# Problemas con script en google sheets para insetar imagenes

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-simple-triggers

Estoy trabajando en un libro en google sheets para llevar un control de pagos, todo va bien pero hice una pestaña para crear un comprobante de pago con ciertos datos de otra pestaña y se traigan de acuerdo con lo que se seleccione en una lista que está en esa pestaña que traera los números de comprobantes y esta misma se actualiza cada vez que uno selecciona un mes o agrega un dato nuevo en cualquier otra pestaña, esto lo hice con un script y funciona perfectamente. Adicionalmente quiero que se inserte una imagen que tiene el mismo nombre que se selecciona en la lista, desde una carpeta de google drive. La imagen se debe insertar entre unas celdas y ajustarse el tamaño y si no está la imagen, me de un mensaje emergente. Ese Script no me funciona, por lo que he investigado me dice que debo validar la aprobación del uso del google drive y ahi es donde no se. Este es el Script completo si alguno me puede ayudar a revisarlo.

```js
function onEdit(e) {  
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet();  
  var editedValue = e.range.getValue();  
  
  // Verifica si se ha editado la celda C1 en la hoja "Resumen"  
  if (editedSheet.getName() == "Resumen" && e.range.getA1Notation() == "C1") {  
    // Actualiza la lista desplegable en "Comprobante de Pago"  
    updateDropdown(editedValue);  

    // Insertar la imagen correspondiente al comprobante seleccionado
    pasteImage(editedValue);
  } else {  
    // Actualiza la lista desplegable en "Comprobante de Pago" si se ha editado una celda en una pestaña de mes  
    updateDropdown(getSelectedMonth());  
  }  
}

function onOpen() { 
  // Actualiza la lista desplegable al abrir la hoja de cálculo 
  updateDropdown(getSelectedMonth()); 
} 

function getSelectedMonth() { 
  var resumenSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Resumen"); 
  return resumenSheet.getRange("C1").getValue(); 
}

function updateDropdown(selectedMonth) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Comprobante de Pago"); 
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(selectedMonth); 
   
  if (dataSheet != null && sheet != null) { 
    var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow(); 
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow).getValues().filter(String); 
    var validationRange = sheet.getRange("D10:F10").setDataValidation( 
      SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation() 
        .requireValueInList(dataRange) 
        .build() 
    ); 
  } 
}

function pasteImage(comprobante) {
  var folderId = "12_dpnGsIXoAJyliH6U6iBha9_TbqaOa0"; // ID de la carpeta que contiene las imágenes
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(comprobante);

  // Verificar si se encontró un archivo con el nombre del comprobante
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    var imageBlob = file.getBlob(); // Obtener el blob de imagen del archivo

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Comprobante de Pago");
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange("F17:I29");

    // Eliminar cualquier contenido existente en el rango objetivo
    targetRange.clear();

    // Insertar la imagen en el rango objetivo
    sheet.insertImage(imageBlob, 6, 17, 4, 13); // Pegar imagen ajustando tamaño a las celdas F17:I29
    
    // Registro para verificar si se llegó a este punto
    console.log("Imagen insertada correctamente.");
  } else {
    // Si no se encuentra la imagen, mostrar un mensaje de alerta
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No se encontró ninguna imagen con el nombre: " + comprobante);
  }
}
```